# How to integrate aws secrets manager with azure CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, azure-devops, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to create a Azure Devops pipeline for my .Net Framework application. The code will be deployed to cloud using aws services. I would like to save all my database connection strings in secrets manager and use it in my app so I don't have to worry about saving passwords in web config. Can someone guide me how to go about this problem ?

Comment: Azure does not have any equivalent of secrents manager?

Answer (score 3):

> **If I understood correct, You want to use AWS secret manager to store
> your secret, but also want to use those secret values in Azure.**

**Prerequisite** : *You need to have an Azure DevOps account and an AWS account.*

**Step 1** : *Store secrets in AWS Secret Manager*

**Step 2** : *To get secrets from Azure DevOps pipeline, you need to create an IAM user with secret manager policy access*

[image]

**Step 3**: *Attach policies for permissions. The user should be able to read and write from the secret manager so we will assign `SecretsManagerReadWrite` policy.*

[image]

**Step 4** : *Copy the access key & secret key.*

**Step 5** : *Open the Azure DevOps panel and and select an organization, then click on Project settings.*

[image]

**Step 6** : *Look for Service connections from the left panel under the Pipelines section.*

[image]

**Step 7** : *Click on New service connection.*

[image]

**Step 8** : *Enter Access key and Secret key and other details*

[image]

**Step 9** : *Create a repo and write azure-pipeline.yml*

`Sample yaml` :

```
name: Test
variables:
  var1: value1
trigger:
- master
jobs:
- job: One
  steps:
  - script: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y jq
      python -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3 setuptools wheel
      pip install awscli --user
    displayName: 'Install tools'
  - task: AWSShellScript@1
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: 'Access To AWS' # Serivce connection name
      regionName: 'eu-west-1'
      scriptType: 'inline'
      inlineScript: |
        /home/vsts/.local/bin/aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id dev/pass | jq -r '.SecretString' | jq -r '.password'
```

**Step 10** : *After you push code to master branch, pipeline will automatically start and you will be see the secure value in the stdout.*

Comment: Can you please elaborate step 9 and step 10 ? Thx

Comment: `azure-pipeline.yml` is where you can retrieve secret from AWS secret manager and use the value. Check input section in `azure-pipeline.yaml` where we are accessing AWS secret manager with CLI. Pipeline will be triggered after you push code to master branch, which can be changed to a specific branch as well, you just need to change the `trigger` directive in pipeline yaml file. And step 10 says that your pipeline is running successfully, as per the configuration. Logs can be checked to analyze and get more granular idea about what's going on.